# Hyperledger fabric Hardware requirement

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using hyperledger fabric-v2.0 which has 5 orderer, 4 peer for two organisation with include ROOT CA and intermediate CA, I would like to know for the above set-up what will be the minimum hardware configuration required please let me know any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I got this UP on Windows. It is better to have min 8 GB RAM for you to try out things.